# Progress bar appearing after the page loaded

Tags: jquery, progress-bar

I am trying to show the progress of file upload thru jQuery. File upload works fine. But progress bar appears after the file is uploaded.

That is progress bar shown in 100%. But when I 'alert' I can see the progress bar.

Any idea why progress bar is not shown with below sample ?

```
<body>
    <div id="progressbar"></div>
    <div id="status"></div>
</body>
    <script>
              $("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
               updateStatus();
        </script>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using ie8?is it working on other browser?

Comment: Nope i am using Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: this could be an issue with the upload process... try it on the local system and it should work fine... does it?